# PHPMailer issue - Email appears to send with no errors

Tags: webforms, phpmailer

The following code worked before I added the $_POSTs and populated the email variables manually but doesn't work now I've added them. Looking at the output, it appears that everything is OK, but I do not receive an the email (I've tried two different "To" addresses just incase it's an inbound server issue. Any thoughts?

`

```
`<?php
  require("PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php");
  require("PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php");
  require_once 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php'; 
    
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $name=$_POST['name'];
   $email=$_POST['email'];
   $phone=$_POST['phone'];
   $date=$_POST['date'];
   $p_name=$_POST['p_name'];
   $dob=$_POST['dob'];
   $gender=$_POST['gender'];
   $height=$_POST['height'];
   $weight=$_POST['weight'];
   $oxygen=$_POST['oxygen'];
   $message=$_POST['message'];
  
  
  
  $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.xxxx.co.uk";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "website@pxxxxxxxx.com";
    $mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->Subject = "Website Repatriation Form";
    $mail->Body = "Contact Name: ".$name."\n"."Contact Phone No: ".$phone."\n"."Patient's Name: ".$p_name."\n"."Date of Birth: ".$dob."\n"."Gender: ".$gender."\n"."Height: ".$height."\n"."Needs Oxygen? :".$oxygen."\n"."Message:"."\n".$message;
    $mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

     if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     } else {
        echo "Message has been sent";
     }
   }
?>`
```

`
With logging turned on, I get the following output:

```
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO xxxxxxxx.com
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<name@domain.com>
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<name@domain.co.uk>
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Mon, 21 Nov 2022 12:24:17 +0100
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: name@domain.co.uk
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Name <name@domain.com>
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Website Repatriation Form
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <WANZgAlHnYVPWwcMaFO7zyV8AXyiFTzo@domain.com>
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.6.5 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Contact Name: Webform name
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Contact Phone No: xxxxxxxxxxx
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Patient's Name: Eric Sprognasty
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date of Birth: 1956-01-01
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Gender: Male
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Height: 5'11"
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Needs Oxygen? :No
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message:
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem aspernatur magnam sapiente dicta, harum quae iure, labore tenetur cumque odio nostrum nesciunt quos tempora maiores animi id et soluta vitae.

2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2022-11-21 11:24:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2022-11-21 11:24:18 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
Message has been sent
```

Running out of ideas. Ran the form with manually set email variables and it worked

Comment: You've based your code on a very old example, but the main thing is to set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2` so you can see what the server is saying.

Comment: Thanks - Looks like the server is processing the message with "2022-11-21 13:20:40 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication succeeded" and "2022-11-21 13:20:40 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Requested mail action okay, completed: id=1M4aEC-1oxexS2YR4-001lZV"

Comment: That confirms that it was sent successfully. Your next task is to figure out where it went. First place to check: your spam folder.